# react-native ios, how to release local images from cache in low memory scenario?

Tags: ios, react-native, memory

I'm working with an app that utalizes a lot of local images i.e. images that have source like `require(../assets/MyImage.png)`.

During development I didn't face any issues, however when I built my app for release on iphone 5s, I started getting random device restarts. After some research I found out that whenever I was browsing through my app and loading all these various images (some of them are heavy background images) they were persisted in iOS memory / RAM.

Memory was not cleared after I unmounted screens / navigated to different screens, it just kept growing while I was using my app and loading new images and eventually app crashed.

I found that there is an AppDelegate method in iOS called `didReceiveMemoryWarning` that can be used to perform cache clearing when app is using too much memory, but I can't figure out what cache and how I should clear to remove react-native images in iOS?

Would appreciate any advice on the topic.

NOTE: I've read somewhere that iOS will auto manage memory, but after using XCode memory profiler and Instruments, I don't believe this is happening, it just keeps growing upwards whenever new resource is mounted on the screen.

Memory profiler output
[image]

Comment: Have you run the app through the memory profiler to check for leaks? Sounds like something is keeping your images in RAM and it may be a retain cycle.

Comment: @Dare I updated question with screenshot from memory profiler. As `react-native` dev, I'm mostly familiar with JavaScript side of it, so I'm not sure how to read this profiler, but I can tell that it's looking bad. Would appreciate suggestions / links to sources that could explain how to read this.

Comment: The profiler output seems to indicate you do have leaks. iOS can only manage your memory assuming you do not write a retain cycle. If that happens, ARC will never release your images. I would try and investigate for any obvious retail cycles in your controllers where children may be retaining their parents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After various attempts to find a solution I ended up using following image package https://github.com/DylanVann/react-native-fast-image

It improved memory management and performance of my images. As additional benefit it allows to use WebP images in iOS project which reduced my bundle size substantially.